how to find the points of intersections between the two complex function
Given two complex functions in one cartesian coordinate system, how to find the points of intersections between the two complex functions?

You solve the equation $f(z) = g(z)$? I mean, without context, this is a pretty vague question if you ask me

Functions don't have intersections. Perhaps you are asking about the intersections of the graphs of the two functions, in which case, you draw those two graphs (or get a calculator/computer/grad student to graph them for you) and you look at the graphs and you see where they intersect.
